# Problemas com lógica de programação

Tags: c

estudo C básico e estou com problemas em lógica, estou fazendo alguns exercicios que exige cálculos como fatoração decomposição e até mesmo problemas como "A tem o dobro da idade de B quando A tinha a idade de B, se somarmos a idade de A e B hoje teriamos 81 anos" eu não consigo por os cálculos no programa o que eu posso fazer, o que eu posso estudar.

exemplo esse exercicio é de fatoração:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*fazer um programa para deconpor um numero por numeros primos*/

int main()
{
    int num,primo,i,cont=0, deco, aux=0;

    printf("digite um numero para ele ser doconposto:\n");
    scanf("%i", &num);
    printf("digite um numero primo:\n");
    scanf("%i", &primo);

    for(i=1;i<=primo;i++)
    {
        aux=primo%i;

        if(aux==0)
            cont++;

        if(cont==2)
        {
            deco=num%primo;
            printf("%i", deco);
        }

        else if(cont!=2)
        {
            printf("nao eh um numero primo digite outro numero:\n");
            scanf("%i", &primo);
        }

        if(deco!=1)
        {
            printf("digite outro numero:\n");
            scanf("%i", &primo);
        }

        if(deco==1)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A dificuldade é em fazer o código?

Comment: sim a dificuldade é em fazer o codigo

Comment: Já iniciou alguma coisa? você quer fazer esse problema da idade em código?

Comment: Olá. Não está muito claro o que você está perguntando. Você chegou a tentar algo para um dos problemas que menciona? Se sim, poderia incluir o seu código na pergunta. Assim, fica mais fácil da comunidade te ajudar.

Comment: pronto luiz eu coloquei um exemplo

Comment: Você sabe resolver o problema matematicamente?

Comment: sim eu sei, ja tambem o resolsovi com um pseudocodigo mas ainda assim nao concigo fazer a converção para o programa

Comment: olha galera eu so preciso saber passar qualquer coisa do papel para o IDE e funcionar eu preciso de um material de estudo é isso que eu preciso, se alguem souber indicar ficarei grato

Comment: Se o que você precisa é material de estudo, dê uma olhada [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/349/material-em-portugu%C3%AAs-para-iniciantes-em-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o), e especialmente no final da nossa [tag wiki de C](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info). O formato de perguntas e respostas deste site não funciona bem para recomendações desse tipo, e por isso vou encerrar a pergunta ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja esses tutoriais do Julia Battisti te ajudam: http://juliobattisti.com.br/tutoriais/katiaduarte/cbasico001.asp (C Básico)

Não tem muito segredo em passar esses problemas simples de PORTUGOL para C. Talvez só não conheça o correpondente ou não saiba algunes detalhes.

```
A+A+B = 81
81 / 3 = 27
A = 54
B = 27
```

Comment: Olá @lcssanches e bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Faça um resumo do tutorial e publique o link apenas como uma referência. Se um dia o link sair do ar, outros operadores que encontrarem esta pergunta ainda poderão se beneficiar de sua resposta. Dê uma olhada na [help] conhecer melhor o modelo do [pt.so] sempre que precisar!